# Python: how to replace str in df to np.nan?

Tags: python, arrays, nan

I have a dataframe X. X contains strs and numeric values. I need to replace all the strs in the whole dataframe into np.nan.
I tried several methods:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKW7S.png)
but there is something wrong. How can I change them?

Comment: You should paste the code here, not an image, with a minimum reproducible example: meaning some small X and the output after trying those three techniques.

Comment: How are you creating said dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the applymap function along with a custom lambda function to detect if a value is an instance of a string (str) and replacing it with np.nan.

Here is a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'A': [1, 'apple', 3],
    'B': ['banana', 2, 'cherry'],
    'C': [1, 2, 3]
}
X = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Replace strings with np.nan
X = X.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, str) else x)

print(X)
```